# Why does the variable type change inside the each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I want to increment different variables based on the value of a calculated variable inside a loop. I am declaring the variables outside the loop, but once inside the loop, they become undefined. Why is this happening?

```
var fetchedDesignOpps = function (designopps)
{
    var oppAging30 = 0; //typeof returns 'number'
    var oppAging60 = 0; //typeof returns 'number'
    var oppAging90 = 0; //typeof returns 'number'
    $.each(designopps.cards, function (index, designopp)
    {
        console.log(typeof oppAging30); //typeof returns 'undefined' - WHY??
        var displayDate = ( convertDate(designopp.dateLastActivity) );
        console.log(displayDate); //returns either 30, 60, or 90. typeof returns 'number' - this part is working
        if (displayDate == 30)
        {
            oppAging30++;
        } else if (displayDate == 60)
        {
            oppAging60++;
        } else
        {
            oppAging90++;
        }
    });
};
```

Here is the json for `designopps.cards`

```
{"cards":[{"id":"575b2831cc53595f4a1c0f8f","name":"Customer 1","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T20:52:40.680Z"},{"id":"56b01bd9e13b0a19089b2aed","name":"Customer 2","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T20:41:02.613Z"},{"id":"56392581b258f000e09749d3","name":"Customer 3","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T20:22:32.017Z"},{"id":"575b1a2317c190ce8d037ca4","name":"Customer 4","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T20:22:06.001Z"},{"id":"55bbcfcf81a608d6f1c9a7df","name":"Customer 5","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T19:26:31.843Z"},{"id":"565e061fa054f3967dcbb561","name":"Customer 6","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T17:05:20.626Z"},{"id":"5723515ebb2c969293b88fd1","name":"Customer 7","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T16:37:35.534Z"},{"id":"56d9a419cb4f3be26b2c8cc8","name":"Customer 8","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-10T16:27:19.116Z"},{"id":"55f04b753c825b3af5b46976","name":"Customer 9","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-07T18:32:10.165Z"},{"id":"570e98edf5709b4e51734976","name":"Customer 10","dateLastActivity":"2016-06-07T18:26:13.207Z"},}]}
```

Comment: ...because you're in a new function scope?

Comment: Can you give us the `designopps` so we can try to replicate your problem.

Comment: Your code works, with `typeof oppAging30` being `"number"` as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/kp688sbp/1/ (I added a dummy `convertDate()` function to make it run.)

Comment: `typeof returns 'undefined'` is completely impossible in the code you show here. The code you show here and the code you actually run are different.